# javascript function response from AJAX call returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

wanted to check a value through ajax for validation purpose. my function getting respose `true` or `false`. but cannot return reponse to function `callback_validation`.

when i call below function its returning `undefined.`

```
console.log(callback_validation('value',<object>)); /* here its returning undefined */
```

> Above function supposed to return me **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

***find my action javascript function here:***

```
        function callback_validation($val,$field){
        var $jObj=[],$data={
            ci: $ci,
            ui: $ui
        };
        $data[$field.attr('name')]=$val;
        $jObj.push($data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify($jObj)); /* CONSOLE OUTPUT: [{"ci":"","ui":"4934","refno":"s"}] */
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {           
                /* console.log(res.valid); */ /* here its returning true / false */
                return res.valid;
            },
            data: $data,
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log('Details: ' + desc + '\nError:' + err + '\n');
                return false;
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

Comment: ajax is doing asynchronous call. You can't return the value as above. One option is to make the call sync add option as `async: "false",` OR with async  call try to pass a callback function to your `callback_validation` which will get invoked on ajax response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous meaning that you cannot return a value from the `callback_validation` that depends on the result of the AJAX call. The reason for that is because the `success` callback (which is the only place where you know the value) could be executed much after the function has already returned.

So I would recommend you start using the async pattern and have your function take a callback instead of returning a value:

```
function callback_validation($val, $field, resultCallback) {
    var $jObj=[], $data={
        ci: $ci,
        ui: $ui
    };
    $data[$field.attr('name')]=$val;
    $jObj.push($data);

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (res) {           
            resultCallback(res.valid);
        },
        data: $data,
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log('Details: ' + desc + '\nError:' + err + '\n');
            resultCallback(false);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

and now you can call your function like that:

```
callback_validation('value',<object>, function(result) {
    console.log(result); // this will print true or false
});
```

It's just the asynchronous pattern of programming that you should get accustomed too if you are doing AJAX calls.

Comment: you solution works fine! but it would be easy if i could call function like this `return callback_validation('value',<object>);` .  also i'm getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`

Comment: @SyedNizamudeen you might think it would be easier, but it's not because it's **asynchronous**.

Comment: @freedomn-m can help me on this?

Comment: It's not a matter of what is easier, but what is technically possible. As I mentioned if you are doing AJAX programming you'd better get accustomed to the asynchronous patterns of coding - which is use callbacks and not return values from functions. The sooner you get accustomed to this style, the better.

Comment: @SyedNizamudeen yes, read *and understand* the link for the possible duplicate.  As Darin states, it's a paradigm-shift in your coding toolset.